# how to get current value of sequence in hsqldb

Tags: hsqldb

How do I get the current value of a sequence in the HSQLDB?

I know I can get the "next value" with "call next value" but I want to get the "last given out value" basically, similar to postgres' `last_value` https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/78228/16892

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work:

`select (CAST(next_value AS INTEGER) - 1) from information_schema.sequences where sequence_name = upper('<your seq name>')`

assuming your sequence increments by 1 and its a normal INT type sequence.

ref: http://hsqldb.10974.n7.nabble.com/Current-value-of-a-sequence-td427.html

but it appears the "commit" bug they refer to has been fixed (at least in v2.3.2), as far as you can see the value without having to do commit yet.

Note also that this method is "sometimes flakey" with 2.3.2 but seems to work as expected with v2.3.6

Answer (score 0):

Things have advanced in the last 10 years since the discussion in the mailing list. For general use, there is now the `CURRENT VALUE FOR sequence_name` expression, which returns the last value used in the session. See the Guide at http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_value_expression which has the example below:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE(COL1, COL2) VALUES 2, NEXT VALUE FOR MYSEQUENCE;
INSERT INTO CHILDTABLE(COL1, COL2) VALUES 10, CURRENT VALUE FOR MYSEQUENCE;
```

Comment: OK this does work, thanks! caveats:requires  2.5, with 2.3 `user lacks privilege or object not found: CURRENT` or `unexpected token: FOR`.  Requires a transaction.  If you're in "autoCommit" mode it returns null.  If you just query for the current value without using it first (within a transaction) it returns null.  So basically the same as postgres' `currval` :)